# How do I control ip routing in the new firewalld?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I have the following scenario:

Our fedora server is connected to the internet on `eth0` and has a second nic, `wlan0` acting as an access point. The purpose of the access point is to provide a connection for mobile users to the services running on the server. We do NOT want users connecting on that access point to use the internet connection on the other NIC.

If it had been an older version of Fedora, I would do this in iptables:

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

**The new network manager doesn't use `iptables` any more, so how do I establish the same effect?**

Comment: What services is the server providing?  Are clients accessing Samba drives or opening ssh shells?

Comment: @Creek. Not sure how your question is relevant. It is a traffic issue not a service issue. All traffic in and out of eth0 should not cross to wlan0 and all trafic in and out of wlan0 should not cross to eth0. It could be for any services.

Comment: What does "The new network manager doesn't use iptables any more" mean? I am not familiar with NetworkManager. Did it offer an interface for Netfilter configuration? You should not need NetworkManager for configuring Netfilter.

Comment: @Octopus if forwarding isn't enabled in the kernel then the box won't forward traffic, end of story.  But if clients are opening shells then the problem becomes how do you stop a user from sending traffic out of `eth0`